How can I merge the images from the same day in Sentinel 2?
I want to write a code in Google Earth Engine that merges images from the same day and calculates the LAI index for daily images.
Finally, add all the images to the layers and get their shape files. But I get the following error.
Line 46: A mapped function's arguments cannot be used in client-side operations
Code link: https://code.earthengine.google.com/5776b74fd858a4708f84c6a6dac8aa9c
// Define the catchment area 
var catchment = table;

// Set the date range
var startDate = ee.Date('2017-01-01');
var endDate = ee.Date('2018-12-31');

// Load Sentinel-2 
var sentinel2 = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2_HARMONIZED')
  .filterBounds(catchment)
  .filterDate(startDate, endDate)
  .filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE', 20))  // Less than 20% cloud cover
  .map(function(image) {
    return image.clip(catchment);  // Clip to catchment area
  });

// Function to calculate LAI
function calculateLAI(image) {
 var bands = image.select(['B2', 'B4', 'B8']).multiply(0.0001)
 var ndvi = bands.normalizedDifference(['B8','B4']).rename('ndvi')
 var evi = bands.expression('2.5 * ((nir - red) / (nir + 6 * red - 7.5 * blue + 1))', {
 'nir': bands.select('B8'), 'red': bands.select('B4'), 'blue': bands.select('B2')
 }).rename('evi');
 var lai = evi.expression('3.618 * evi - 0.118', {'evi': evi.select('evi')}).rename('lai')
 return image.addBands(lai.rename('LAI'))
 .copyProperties(image, ['system:time_start','system:time_end'])
}

// Calculate LAI for each image
var laiCollection = sentinel2.map(calculateLAI);

// Generate a list of daily dates within the range
var dailyDates = ee.List.sequence(0, endDate.difference(startDate, 'day').subtract(1), 1)
  .map(function(day) {
    return startDate.advance(day, 'day');
  });

// Aggregate images to create daily LAI layers by merging images on the same date
var dailyLAI = ee.ImageCollection(dailyDates.map(function(date) {
  date = ee.Date(date);
  
  // Filter the LAI collection to get images for this specific day
  var dailyImages = laiCollection.filterDate(date, date.advance(1, 'day'));
  
  // Merge all images of the same day
  var dailyLAIMean = dailyImages.select('LAI')
    .set('system:time_start', date.millis())
    .set('date', date.format('YYYY-MM-dd'));
  
  // Display the layer on the map
  Map.addLayer(dailyLAIMean, {min: 0, max: 6, palette: ['blue', 'green', 'yellow', 'red']}, 'LAI ' + date.format('YYYY-MM-dd').getInfo());
  
  return dailyLAIMean;
}));

// Export each daily LAI image as a shapefile
dailyLAI.toList(dailyLAI.size()).map(function(image) {
  image = ee.Image(image);
  var dateStr = ee.Date(image.get('system:time_start')).format('YYYYMMdd').getInfo();

  Export.table.toDrive({
    collection: image.reduceToVectors({
      reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
      geometry: catchment,
      scale: 10,
      maxPixels: 1e9,
      geometryType: 'polygon'
    }),
    description: 'LAI_' + dateStr,
    folder: 'LAI_Export',
    fileFormat: 'SHP'
  });
});

